# how to create frame(frame, window) using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, graphics, frame

I've been using Node for a while, and now want to build a basic browser(just a navigation with history). I've stuck on a problem:
How can I create GUI using Node.js?

I've seen frameworks on this topic, but I'm confused by all of them.
Please help!

Comment: You better take a look at NW.JS or Electron for this. Also please post a specific problem we can help you with.

Comment: In Windows, Electron creates 4 heavy Windows processes using a total of 60 MB of memory just for an app that creates a plain window.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're familiar with [electron](https://electron.atom.io/) or [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) frameworks.

They will help you to create executable, finally.

When you're setup with those, simply use any javascript drawing lib.

Comment: There is also NW.JS which is kind of easier for starters in my opinion.

Comment: @Bellian yeah, you're right. I'll add it into answer.

Comment: See my comment above. I've been looking for a lighter GUI framework, but they all seem to have been abandoned: Deskshell and Neutralino being examples.